# How do pass the wordnet database in a SynonimMap in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, wordnet

The class WordnetSynonymParser how can I get the databse wordnet a map of synonyms? I saw that there WordnetSynonimParser the class but do not know if it suits my purpose, to expand queries through synonyms in WordNet.

Answer (score 0):

`WordnetSynonymParser` is a `SynonymMap.Builder`.  Once you have added the appropriate `Reader`s to the parser, call `build()` to get a `SynonymMap`, which is passed into the constructor of a [`SynonymnFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html).  That filter should then be defined as a part of your `Analyzer`, similar to the example in the [Analyzer documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html).

Something like:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
 @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    Tokenizer source = new FooTokenizer(reader);
    TokenStream filter = new FooFilter(source);
    //etc...

    WordnetSynonymParser parser = new WordnetSynonymParser(true, false, analyzer);
    parser.add(wordnetReader);
    filter = new SynonymFilter(filter, parser.build(), true);

    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
  }
};
```